# Syntax error when trying to access a MySql database via Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to get Slick set up to access a MySQL database, and having a bit of trouble. I've put together the following code:

```
case class FieldValue(fieldName: String, fieldValue: String)

class FieldValues(tag: Tag) extends Table[FieldValue](tag, "FieldValues") {
  def fieldName = column[String]("fieldName")
  def fieldValue = column[String]("fieldValueID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def * = (fieldName, fieldValue) <> (FieldValue.tupled, FieldValue.unapply)
}

object SlickTest extends App {
  val db = Database.forConfig("validation_db")
  val simplesql = sql"select fieldValueID from FieldValues".as[(String)]
  val simplequeryf = db.run(simplesql)
  val simplequeryout = Await.result(simplequeryf, 1 second)
  simplequeryout.foreach(println)

  lazy val slickquery = TableQuery[FieldValues]
  val slickqueryf = db.run(slickquery.result)
  val slickqueryout = Await.result(slickqueryf, 1 second)
  slickqueryout.foreach(println)
}
```

As you'll see, it runs two queries - the first uses simple SQL (and works fine), whereas the second uses the Slick method. The second, unfortunately, throws up the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c
orresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"FieldValues"' at line 1
```

The fact that it quotes the table name in double quotes within single quotes makes me wonder if it's related to MySql's ANSI_QUOTES option, but I'm unsure. For reference, here's my application.conf:

```
validation_db = {
  driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
  url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/validation?serverTimezone=UTC",
  user = "root",
  password = "password",
  connectionPool = disabled,
  useSSL=false
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, setting SQL_MODE to ANSI_QUOTES on the server does indeed solve this, but it's a slightly sub-optimal solution because others interact with that server and may not realize that this switch has been made - if anyone has any ideas for an alternative solution then I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Slick composes SQL, and how fields are quoted or not, is controlled by importing a "profile". There's a different profile for each relational database.

One possibility is that you may see this error if you have imported the incorrect Slick profile.

For MySQL, you should have an import in your code equivalent to:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
```

Comment: thank you - I can't try that right now but as soon as I can, I will.